# How to create a hook in an extension?

Tags: extension, developer, hooks

I want to give others the chance to do something when certain events happen in my extension.

So to be clear: I'm not wanting to use existing hooks in my extension, I'm wanting to create a new hook that my extension will invoke and other code may choose to react to.

I couldn't find anything in the [developers' guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks) about this. Looking at the source makes me think that maybe I should be doing something with `CRM_Utils_Hook` or perhaps `\Civi::dispatcher()->dispatch('hook_my_new_hook', $some_event_object)`?

Is there a standardised way to do this? Are there any good examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the 'normal' way pretty ugly.

- listing the args by name in an array, then
- supplying the args, then
- needing to pass by ref a NULL/dummy variable for each of the remaining 6 or was it 7? arguments - this is ugly and error prone and passing `CRM_Core_DAO::$_nullObject` is risky as it allows the hook to overwrite that so it's no longer NULL.

I think the following can be a nicer approach, here's an example:

### Fire an event

```
// Create an event object with all the data you wan to pass in.
$event = Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent::create(
  ['fname' => $fname, 'votes' => &$votes]);
Civi::dispatcher()->dispatch('civi.something.you.make.up', $event);
```

### Example listener

```
function your_listener_callable($event) {
  print "running " . __FUNCTION__ . "\n";
  // We can overwrite data
  $event->fname = 'Wilma Flintstone';
  // We can alter anything passed by reference.
  $event->votes++;
  // To return a value you need to pass it in an array like so:
  $event->addReturnValues(['Successfully recorded votes!']);
  // We can't write any properties that the event did
  // not originally have defined, so this won't work:
  $event->friend = 'Barney';
}
```

### Use data resulting from the event

This code would come directly after the 'Fire an event' code.

```
print "$fname ($event->fname) now has $votes votes.\n";
$return = $event->getReturnValues();
print "The hook returned: $return[0]\n";
// $event->friend === NULL
```

### Link your listener to the event.

You'd normally do this in a `hook_civicrm_container()` function to ensure it is only added once.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_container().
 *
 * @link https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_container/
 */
function myext_civicrm_container($container) {
  // https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/
  $container->findDefinition('dispatcher')
  ->addMethodCall('addListener', [
    'civi.something.you.made.up',
    'your_listener_callable']);
}
```

### Full working command line example

You can run this with `cv scr hookexample.php`

```
<?php
use \Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent;

if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
  http_response_code(404);
  exit;
}

function your_listener_callable($event) {
  print "running " . __FUNCTION__ . "\n";
  // We can overwrite data passed by value, but that's probably confusing.
  $event->fname = 'Wilma Flintstone';
  // We can alter anything passed by reference.
  $event->votes++;
  // To return a value you need to pass it in an array like so:
  $event->addReturnValues(['Successfully recorded votes!']);
  // We can't write any properties that the event did not originally 
  // have defined, so this won't work:
  $event->friend = 'Barney';
}

// As this is a single-pass script we can just do this:
Civi::dispatcher()->addListener('civi.something.you.make.up', 'your_listener_callable');

$votes = 0;
$fname = 'Wilma';
print "$fname has $votes votes.\n";

$event = GenericHookEvent::create(['fname' => 'Wilma', 'votes' => &$votes]);
Civi::dispatcher()->dispatch('civi.something.you.make.up', $event);

$return = $event->getReturnValues();

print "$fname ($event->fname) now has $votes votes.\n";
print "The hook returned: $return[0]\n";
// $event->friend is NULL.
```

Outputs:

```
Wilma has 0 votes.
running your_listener_callable
Wilma (Wilma Flintstone) now has 1 votes.
The hook returned: Successfully recorded votes!
```

Answer (score 7):

> ### EDIT
>
> This answer is now deprecated, you should use [@bgm's answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/30933/35) instead, or for an alternative and possibly cleaner approach, try [my other answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/39948/35)

All thanks to the code example link in [Eric's answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/25083/35) here's a simplified example of how to offer up a hook (`my_new_hook`) which takes one argument, `$the_argument`:

```
CRM_Utils_Hook::singleton()->invoke(
  1, $the_argument,
  $dummy, $dummy, $dummy, $dummy, $dummy,
  'my_new_hook');
```

Then other extensions can include functions like

```
function myextension_my_new_hook($arg) {
  do_something_with($arg);
}
```

The `$dummy` is just because we must pass a variable (since it's passed by reference), but this hook does not need it. If you had a hook that took two arguments, you'd use `2` in place of `1` and replace the first `$dummy` with your actual second argument etc. up to 6.

Nb. this code assumes CiviCRM 4.5+, but obviously you're not using anything older than that these days, right?!

Comment: Instead of `$dummy` you could use `CRM_Core_DAO::$_nullObject`

Comment: Yep, but not sure what the advantage of that is?

Comment: There is no advantage except that is somehow a standard way of doing such things in CiviCRM.

Comment: Standards are important, I agree. However in this case it is a little odd as the reason parameters have to be passed in this way is because they are passed by reference so that the function receiving them can change them. Passing a static variable could result in that static var being changed, so I think the way I've done it is safer as well as clearer and more succinct.

Comment: Ah I have never thought about your reasning and that makes sense.

Comment: Note the `invoke()` syntax with the first parameter being an integer is now deprecated.  See the named parameter example from @bgm

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of a hook we created for CiviRules:

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/blob/master/CRM/Civirules/Utils/HookInvoker.php

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: In case you have not noticed, your link is now broken and I am not sure the repository is still around.

Comment: The repository moved to GitLab so should now be https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/blob/master/CRM/Civirules/Utils/HookInvoker.php

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using the named parameter syntax:

```
CRM_Utils_Hook::singleton()->invoke(
  ['pdf', 'pdf_variables', 'receipt'],
  $pdf, $pdf_variables, $receipt,
  CRM_Utils_Hook::$_nullObject, CRM_Utils_Hook::$_nullObject, CRM_Utils_Hook::$_nullObject,
  'cdntaxreceipts_writeReceipt');
```

One advantage of this syntax, is that extension can then implement the hook with the Symfony syntax. When managed by Symfony, it's easier to change the priority or add/remove hooks from other extensions.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_civicrm_container().
 *
 * @link https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_container/
 */
function myext_civicrm_container($container) {
  // https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/usage/symfony/
  $container->findDefinition('dispatcher')
    ->addMethodCall('addListener', ['hook_cdntaxreceipts_writeReceipt', 'myext_cdntaxreceipts_symfony_writeReceipt']);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_cdntaxreceipts_writeReceipt() via Symfony.
 *
 * @see myext_civicrm_container()
 */
function myext_cdntaxreceipts_symfony_writeReceipt($event) {
  // Access the parameters with:
  // $event->pdf;
  // $event->pdf_variables;
  // $event->receipt;
}
```

Note that the implementing function `myext_cdntaxreceipts_symfony_writeReceipt` has `symfony` in the name only to avoid being called by the traditional hook system. We can name the function however we want.